# What examples, exercises, topics, etc should I treat when teaching category theory to non-math people?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, education

A couple friends of mine have become very enthusiastic about learning category theory (which I know at the level of category theory for the working mathematician), so I'm giving them lessons. One is a linguist and therefore quasi-mathy, the other studies ancient arabic poetry and has never previously been mathy, just became curious about set theory and category theory because they kept cropping up in philosophical discussions. The first session went really well, but there are a few points I need advice on

1) I know virtually nothing about language and very little about logic or philosophy, so my stock of examples is meager. I can only handwavily talk about categories of statements with arrows corresponding to implication so many times. I need lots of examples!

2) It's hard to know what they'll be excited about. I tried introducing groups (as one object categories) and showed them the integers and the symmetries of the square as such, in hopes of being able to use Grp for future examples. That would have lifted the top of my head off as a math newbie. They thought the idea was alright but weren't enthused. On the other hand they lost their heads when I explained what a commutative diagram is. One pointed at my example and said "that. is. sexy." Things I will not even consider include completeness criteria, theory of monads and the set valued yoneda lemma. I think limits and colimits and adjointness will be really appealing to them. I am doubtful about representability. It would be nice to be able to show them things which are surprising to them, which might be difficult since they have so few mathematical preconceptions to ruin.

3) They wanted exercises. It seems unlikely to me that they'll actually do them, but on the off chance that they do, I'm not sure how to come up with ones that align with their interests when I haven't got any understanding of their interests.

Comment: Off the top of my head, maybe topos theory and its connections to logic might be interesting.  Not sure how to introduce that to non-mathy people, though, especially if it's also not CS people where you could transition into it by connecting cartesian closed categories and simply-typed lambda calculus.

Comment: $\textbf{Set}$ might be a good example to use before doing groups.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe the free cartesian closed categories, with objects being "formal products of atomics" and arrows being "simply typed lambda expressions up to $\beta\eta$-equivalence" might be an appealing example of a category from a linguistic perspective.

Comment: I completely agree Kaj. Just need a good second category to send into Set.

Daniel, I love the suggestions, although I unfortunately think they are too difficult to put into practice.

Comment: Personally, other than perhaps the social aspect, you're probably wasting your and their time. Unless you think there's some reasonable chance that you'll spark a commitment to the equivalent of *at least* the effort of a full-year course in them, it's unlikely that they will get much useful out of it. Just a) reflect on how much effort *you* put in to learn these things and b) flip the situation: could you learn more than a few random factoids about ancient Arabic poetry starting from nothing given e.g. less than 20 hours of instruction from a non-educator or even a professional educator?

Comment: Regarding your thought experiment: I think I'd probably get only a cursory understanding of the basics of ancient Arabic poetry, but if satisfaction for me meant anything more than that I wouldn't have asked for such a lesson, so I imagine I'd be pretty happy with the results.

Comment: About exercises: I suggest to look for some easy algebraic exercises for *semigroups* (monoids), e.g. if we have a left unit and a right unit in a semigroup then they are equal, similarly about inverses. Also, categories and functors themselves serve as good examples.

Comment: I am also interested in this question but have no real answers, except to second that if you can get them to understand quantifiers as adjoints, they might die. You can get lots more examples from individual posets, since they liked diagrams. References that could be useful include "Sets for Mathematics" by Lawvere-Scganuel and "Category Theory for Scientists" by David Spivak. I also find Derek's comment elitist and absurd, and hope you manage to get a bit of something across!

Comment: @KevinCarlson I figured there'd be a response like this. Do you also find the statement "for someone whose never played any sports before, 20 hours of pick-up basketball probably won't qualify them to even enter a competitive league" elitist and absurd? The OP's friends are not incapable of learning category theory, but they probably aren't going to learn it an order of magnitude faster than a math grad student. This suggests level setting expectations and, if coming away with something useful is a goal, single-mindedly focusing on one concept rather than a superficial gloss over everything.

Comment: Who said the OP's friends wanted to enter a competitive league?

Comment: @KevinCarlson I'm trying to give an analogy to "something useful". I have no problem if this just a fun pastime for the OP and his friends. This is what I meant by "social aspects", but, subtracting out the fun of the experience, this may actually have *negative* value to all involved if a superficial coverage leads to misconceptions and false confidence. Alternatively, poorly set expectations can easily lead to frustration and possibly even to a belief by the OP's friends that they *are* incapable of learning category theory because they failed to learn it 10x faster than a math grad student.

Comment: A better analogy would have been to ice hockey. Below a certain level of competence in ice *skating*, you won't be able to play ice hockey *at all*. It's also possible to spend *all* of your time working on ice skating and nothing hockey-specific (and possibly still fail to reach the base level of competence). This latter scenario would correspond to spending all your time on prerequisites, which isn't terrible. Learning to ice skate isn't learning ice hockey, but it's better than not being able to do either.

Comment: @DerekElkins OK, not a bad defense. I guess I just don't buy that category theory has that many prerequisites. The Lawvere-Schanuel book I mentioned is essentially the transcript of a course taught to high schoolers.

Comment: I'm puzzled by your inclination to think that I am overselling their future mathematical mastery, or dooming them to a future under the Dunning Kruger effect. It's uncharitable and even rude. The ice hockey analogy is specious. The mathematical prerequisites for very basic category theory are nearly zero. The mathematical prerequisites to see how it fits into the rest of math are considerable.

Comment: The main obstacle, as I see it, isn't​ lack of mathematical knowledge, it's lack of mathematical maturity. The fact that there are two of them that I'm shepherding carefully will go a long way toward alleviating  this issue, along with judicious choice of topics. I mention I probably won't even touch representability, and you think I'm shooting for the moon? Have some minimum level of faith, please.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I completely agree that category theory doesn't have much prerequisites. I would say naive set theory (and thus also the basics of first-order logic) are all you *need*. But 20 hours is about a month of a high school course which would be roughly 200 hours total i.e. that "full year course" I mentioned. It's not clear you'd get beyond basic set theory following that book in that time. It's also not clear that even in its entirety that book would provide "exciting examples" or that such examples would be forthcoming without more sophistication or at least time.

Comment: @user193072 Completely agree about "lack of mathematical maturity" being an obstacle, but, unfortunately, that's a *big* obstacle that I don't see guidance as dramatically mitigating that. Again, it doesn't *block* anything, it just slows everything down. I actually find it a bit unfortunate that *representability* is what you'd drop as it's equivalent to the notion of a universal property, arguably *the* core idea of category theory, and one with a good amount of weight from a philosophical perspective. It's also a notion that's comparable or simpler than (co)limits and adjunctions.

Comment: Why not the Yoneda lemma? It's one of the most fascinating theorems in mathematics, and one of the most useful. It also has a great analogy with physics: particle physicists only understand particles by how they interact with other particles. Yoneda's is essentially a generalization of this, we can understand mathematical objects completely by how they interact with other objects! A plus is that the proof is astoundingly simple

Comment: By the way, here is a paper that is easily read by nonlinguists/category theorists and applies category theory to linguistics http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.397.6819&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Oh wow didn't realize this was from '17